# H2O - getting cross-validation results from python code

Tags: python, h2o

I'm trying to access the results of some H2O models using python.

I specifically want the cross-validation results. I'm able to get r2 and mae using the code below. I'd ideally like the standard deviation scores too.

I can see the data using `.cross_validation_metrics_summary` , but can't work out how to return the specific values (e.g. cross validation sd)

```py
import h2o 

h2o.init()

def get_model_det(current_model):
    r2_score = current_model.r2(xval = "TRUE")
    mae_score = current_model.mae(xval = "True")
    varimp = current_model.varimp()
    print(current_model.cross_validation_metrics_summary)
    print(r2_score, mae_score)

current_model = h2o.get_model("XGBoost_2_AutoML_20200513_153924")
get_model_det(current_model)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to call out the specific values from `cross_validation_metrics_summary`, you can use the following:

```
current_model.cross_validation_metrics_summary().as_data_frame()[['', 'sd']]
```

The last part `[['', 'sd']]` will call the two columns of interest. `''` is the name of each score (e.g. accuracy, auc) and `'sd'` would give their corresponding standard deviations.

Outputs a table:

```
+-------+----------+--------------+
| index |    ''    |      sd      |
+-------+----------+--------------+
| 0     | accuracy | 0.0048520584 |
| 1     | auc      | 0.011593064  |
| 2     | aucpr    | 0.011920754  |
| ...   | ...      | ...          |
+-------+----------+--------------+
```